# parser XML with javascript from java

Tags: java, javascript, xml

For this use `javax.script.*`

Based on

> DOMParser is not part of JS but part of Mozilla browser which makes it
>   available to script in the browser using XPConnect. An alternative
>   would be to use built-in E4X.

and

> E4X is implemented in Rhino (JavaScript engine written in Java).

try it:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.script.Bindings;
import javax.script.ScriptContext;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class heshCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        scripter();
    }

    public static void scripter() {
        try {

            String Jscript = "var map = {};" + "\n"+
                      "var x = new XML();" +
                      "var person = new XML('<person><name>Bob Smith</name><likes><os>Linux</os><browser>Firefox</browser><language>JavaScript</language><language>Python</language></likes></person>');" +
                      "map[1]=person.name;" +
                      "map[2]=person['name'];" +
                      "map[3]=person.likes.browser;" +
                      "map[4]=person['likes'].browser;";
            ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
            ScriptEngine rhinoEngine = manager.getEngineByName("javascript");
            Bindings bindings = rhinoEngine
                    .getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
            rhinoEngine.eval(Jscript.toString());

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Map<String, String> m = (Map<String, String>) bindings.get("map");
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : m.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
            }
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

but I'm getting error:

```
sun.org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "XML" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#2) in <Unknown source> at line number 2
```

any idea/suggestions ?

Comment: This is a JavaScript problem and has nothing to do with Java, try it in your browser "ReferenceError: XML is not defined"

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: actually, it *does* have something to do with Java, as he's executing JavaScript inside a JVM (from some Java code).

Comment: @JoachimSauer However, the error he is getting is independent of that. He would get the exact same error running JS natively

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I don't actually think so. The error depends on what built-in functionality the JavaScript engine provides.

Comment: I dont know which browser supports `E4X` at the moment , so try to run it in a browser does not make sense

Comment: through usual parse with `DOMParser` does not support so ... ;(

Comment: per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/E4X, `Warning: E4X is obsolete. It has been disabled by default for webpages (content) in Firefox 17, disabled by default for chrome in Firefox 20, and has been removed in Firefox 21. Use DOMParser/DOMSerializer or a non-native JXON algorithm instead.`

Answer (score 0):

The Scripting Programmer guide clearly states that it has excluded E4X (ECMAScript for XML).  Check it out in this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/.

I had a similar problem, where I had to parse XML using java script and obtain the output.  I then used Mozilla Rhino (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino).

It worked well for my situation.

Hope this helps any one who comes across a similar problem.